# How can I use set based logic to replace current loop processing

Tags: t-sql

I want to be able to generate 1  merge statement rather than loop through a lookup table using

a single Set based Recursive CTE statement but im struggling on this.

I have a set of tables which are update by means of a look up table using a merge statement

ChannelInfo

This is the look up table (ChannelInfo) which use [ChannelID]
[image]

I then use channelID to locate and filter data in this table [ChannelReadingMain]

ChannelReadingMain
[image]

Once data is selected out of ChannelReadingMain, then its Merged into a destination table

which is looked up from this table [DeviceChannel] (via ChannelID)

Devicechannel
[image]

So i can loop though and produce  a set of merge Statements which are executed in  squence .,, for example if i wanted to Merge data for ChannelD = 15...then it would be as follows:

```sql
MERGE [ChannelReading_939029_15_27C51350-C2BA-4C67-87F7-F91F56093036] T

USING

(

SELECT

[Si] as SIReading,

[Raw] as RawReading,

[TimeStamp] as ReadingDateTime

FROM

[#ChannelReadingMain]

WHERE

ChannelID = '15'

) S on T.ReadingDateTime = S.ReadingDateTime

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET

THEN

INSERT (ReadingDateTime,SIReading, RawReading)

VALUES (S.ReadingDateTime,S.SIReading, S.RawReading);
```

This is build dynamically... but is run as part of a loop and takes time.

I want to convert this to a single Set based update statement using a CTE

But i get the following error

> Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Line 130
> Reference to database and/or server name in 'b.cte2.ChannelReadingTablename' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

I think this is to do with scope of the Cte in DynamicSQL

How can i utilizie a cte to produce 1 update statement?

The code to recreate this is attached here:

Comment: That query and that error appear to be unrelated. You have no object called `cte2` in the above.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ok can a recursive CTE be used to execute mutiple MERGE statements?

Comment: A CTE is an expression, not a logical flow operator.